# How Laravel requests behave about controller files compilation

Tags: laravel, compilation, controller, request, laravel-5

In Laravel, when a request mapped to a specific controller method is made, does Laravel access/compiles all other controller files or just the file from involved controller?

Comment: When a route is dispatched to a controller only that file is loaded. It's actually loaded through the composer auto loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the classes you create in a Laravel application are loaded as needed. This includes Models, Controllers, Repositories... pretty much everything.

Autoloading is achieved using the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) spec. If you have a namespaced class like...

```
<?php namespace \Foo\Bar;

class Baz {}
```

Then it should live in...

```
app/Foo/Bar/Baz.php
```

When this class is used for the first time, the framework will attempt to load the class from that location.